# When should I Disable Varnish?

Tags: magento2, varnish

I have heard by some developers that while making changes to magento2 backend (like adding a extension), one should disable varnish (so that changes we make get visible on the frontend).

Is that true?

If it is, then, in what scenarios, one should disable varnish, and, under what scenarios, we need not disable varnish?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to disable varnish, right after installation or updates just flush varnish cache and magento cache too...

Comment: Will `bin/magento cache:flush` flush varnish cache?